# Convert to list of dict/type, a list of strings containing lists of strings?

Tags: python, functional-programming, apply, mutation, list-manipulation

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', ['can', 'haz']]
```

Looking to apply a function to each pair of strings, replacing them, including those inside lists. E.g.,

```
f = lambda k,v: {'key': k, 'val': v}
```

So that `f(a)` would become:

```
[{'key': 'foo', 'val': 'bar'}, [{'key': 'can', 'val': 'haz'}]]
```

Above `a` is only 2 dimensions, but I would be interested in *k* dimensions. Started hacking something together with [`boltons.iterutils.remap`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.remap) before it became clear that replacing all non-list elements at each hierarchy level with a `dict` or other `f` is not the right use-case for it…

EDIT: Another example

```
# create some random variables, alternative: `locals().update({c: (round(…`
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z = tuple(
    (round(abs(random()) ** 10, 4)
     if randint(0, 1) % 2 == 0
     else randint(20, 50)
     if randint(0, 1) % 2 == 0
     else ('foo', 'bar', 'can', 'haz', 'bzr')[randint(0, 4)])
           for c in ascii_lowercase)

l1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, [h, i, j, k],
      l, m, n, [o, p, q, r, [s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z], a, b], c, d, e]

g = lambda k,v: {'{}_key'.format(k): k, '{}_val'.format(k): v}
```

When there are pairs of adjacent to each other, it should apply the type constructor T to it, and join (I've got an `add_to` function supporting dicts, lists, and more) any previous directly adjacent—with no list inbetwixt—else the raw scalar should be concatenated onto the list at the same hierarchy it was at before. Here is the expected output of `g(l1)`, excluding evaluation of variables:

```
[
    {'a_key': a, 'a_val': b,
     'c_key': c, 'c_val': d,
     'e_key': e, 'e_val': f},
    g,
    [
        {'h_key': h, 'h_val': i,
         'j_key': j, 'j_val': k}
    ],
    {'l_key': l, 'l_val': m},
    n,
    [
        {'o_key': o, 'o_val': p,
         'q_key': q, 'q_val': r},
        [
            {'s_key': s, 's_val': t,
             'u_key': u, 'u_val': v,
             'w_key': w, 'w_val': x,
             'y_key': y, 'y_val': z}
        ],
        {'a_key': a, 'a_val': b}
    ],
    {'c_key': c, 'c_val': d},
    e
]
```

Comment: Do these values always come in pairs and are always sorted as `['key1', 'val1']` pairs?

Comment: Yes. When uneven though want to push it onto the end of the hierarchy rather than parse it through. That way can handle different levels of the data-structure from the one piece of recursive function.

Comment: Are the 1st two elements always `key` followed by `val` of list in every level? Can it be `['foo',['can','haz'],'bar']`

Comment: Is the order of each dictionary important?

Comment: @Ch3steR No, they can be followed by other lists or by pairs of scalars (`str|int|float`), or by individual scalars (which should end up as just lone elements). @Marcos The idea is that you can pass in an arbitrary function/type, e.g., OrderedDict, your custom class, or what have you.

Comment: Looks like `'a_key'` etc in the big example result should be `f'{a}_key'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pile of mess down below but the core algorithm in `solution()` doesn't seem so bad.  I can't say I like the `sentinel` there but...  it made everything else tidy.

https://repl.it/@altendky/ChartreuseWeightyRoot-10

```py
import functools
import itertools
import random
import string

import attr
import toolz


@attr.s(frozen=True)
class Example:
    source = attr.ib()
    target = attr.ib()
    group_handler = attr.ib()


def random_example():
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z = tuple(
        (round(abs(random.random()) ** 10, 4)
        if random.randint(0, 1) % 2 == 0
        else random.randint(20, 50)
        if random.randint(0, 1) % 2 == 0
        else ('foo', 'bar', 'can', 'haz', 'bzr')[random.randint(0, 4)])
            for c in string.ascii_lowercase)

    l1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, [h, i, j, k],
        l, m, n, [o, p, q, r, [s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z], a, b], c, d, e]

    auauughhghhhh = [
        {f'{a}_key': a, f'{a}_val': b,
        f'{c}_key': c, f'{c}_val': d,
        f'{e}_key': e, f'{e}_val': f},
        g,
        [
            {f'{h}_key': h, f'{h}_val': i,
            f'{j}_key': j, f'{j}_val': k}
        ],
        {f'{l}_key': l, f'{l}_val': m},
        n,
        [
            {f'{o}_key': o, f'{o}_val': p,
            f'{q}_key': q, f'{q}_val': r},
            [
                {f'{s}_key': s, f'{s}_val': t,
                f'{u}_key': u, f'{u}_val': v,
                f'{w}_key': w, f'{w}_val': x,
                f'{y}_key': y, f'{y}_val': z}
            ],
            {f'{a}_key': a, f'{a}_val': b}
        ],
        {f'{c}_key': c, f'{c}_val': d},
        e
    ]

    g = lambda k,v: {'{}_key'.format(k): k, '{}_val'.format(k): v}

    return Example(
        source=l1,
        target=auauughhghhhh,
        group_handler=functools.partial(process_group, paired_sequence_handler=lambda s: build_dict_by_update(s, g)),
    )


def process_group(group, paired_sequence_handler):
    processed_group = []

    if len(group) == 0:
        return processed_group

    odd = (len(group) % 2) != 0
    raw_pairs = group[:-1] if odd else group
    pairs = toolz.partition_all(2, raw_pairs)
    result = paired_sequence_handler(pairs)

    processed_group.append(result)

    if odd:
        processed_group.append(group[-1])

    return processed_group


def build_dict_by_update(sequence, pair_handler):
    result = {}
    for pair in sequence:
        result.update(pair_handler(*pair))

    return result


examples = [
    Example(
        source=['foo', 'bar', ['can', 'haz']],
        target=[{'key': 'foo', 'val': 'bar'}, [{'key': 'can', 'val': 'haz'}]],
        group_handler=functools.partial(process_group, paired_sequence_handler=lambda s: build_dict_by_update(s, lambda k,v: {'key': k, 'val': v})),
    ),
    random_example(),
]


def solution(source, group_handler):
    built = []
    group = []

    sentinel = object()

    for value in itertools.chain(source, [sentinel]):
        if not isinstance(value, list) and value is not sentinel:
            group.append(value)
            continue

        built.extend(group_handler(group))
        group = []

        if value is sentinel:
            break

        result = solution(
            source=value,
            group_handler=group_handler,
        )
        built.append(result)

    return built



for example in examples:
    result = solution(
        source=example.source,
        group_handler=example.group_handler,
    )

    succeeded = result == example.target

    print('?', succeeded)

    if not succeeded:
        print('?  ', example.target)
        print('?  ', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need recursion in order to support an undefined number of levels.

Assuming your levels always have 2 or 3 items in the lists at each level, the recursive function could look like this:

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', ['can', 'haz']]

def f(a):
    k,v,b,*_ = a+[None]
    result = [{"key":k,"val":v}]
    if b: result.append(f(b))
    return result
```

output:

```
print(f(a))

# [{'key': 'foo', 'val': 'bar'}, [{'key': 'can', 'val': 'haz'}]]


b = ['foo', 'bar', ['can', 'haz', ['boo','yah',['dino','dog']]]]
print(f(b))
[
  {'key': 'foo', 'val': 'bar'},
  [
     {'key': 'can', 'val': 'haz'},
     [
        {'key': 'boo', 'val': 'yah'},
        [
          {'key': 'dino', 'val': 'dog'}
        ]
     ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but can this be generalised for more than 2 or 3 items in the list?

Comment: Of course. But you would have to describe the conventions you are using to determine the relationship between items.  A recursive list of lists could mean anything.  Such a data structure would be very hard to use and maintain.  You should consider using a more explicit hierarchy of objects and classes.

Comment: To illustrate with an example, where each alphabetical letter refers to a scalar (`int|float|str`). When there are pairs of scalars adjacent to each other, it should apply the type constructor T to it, and join any previous directly adjacent—with no list inbetwixt—else the raw scalar should be concatenated onto the list at the same hierarchy it was at before. I'll edit my initial question with a bigger example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming consecutive content of every each one of the lists is always either key-val pair or a list:

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', ['can', 'haz']]

def f(a):
  itr = iter(a)
  return [f(a) if isinstance(x, list) else {'key': x, 'val': next(itr)} for x in itr]

# >>> f(a)
# [{'key': 'foo', 'val': 'bar'}, [{'key': 'can', 'val': 'haz'}]]
```

---

**Update:**

Ok, I must say this gave me a bit of a headache but since it's an interesting problem and great opportunity to learn something new, here it is.
A function that does **exactly**<sup>1</sup> what you wanted and since you have some issues with recursive operations:

> With your precise function and input I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

It does it **without recursion**. I'm sure this is not the *ultimate* solution but it works:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def traverse(lst):
  stack = [lst]
  res = [[]]

  substack = stack[0]
  subres = res[0]

  depth = 0

  while stack:
    if substack:
      if isinstance(substack[0], list):
        substack = substack[0]
        subres.append([])
        subres = subres[-1]
        depth += 1
      else:
        if len(substack) > 1 and not isinstance(substack[1], list):
            subres.append({'key': substack.pop(0), 'val': substack.pop(0)})
        else:
          subres.append(substack.pop(0))
    else:
        substack = reduce(operator.getitem, [0] * depth, stack)
        subres = reduce(operator.getitem, [-1] * depth, res)
        depth -= 1
        substack.pop(0)

  return res[0]
```

[Live Demo](http://pythontutor.com/live.html?fbclid=IwAR2jZeYE0C2kgQ72rMOXdLLKySXyHRn2PY-MUM8B6Ua67JcvXm5rlTybq9k#code=from%20random%20import%20random,%20randint%0Afrom%20string%20import%20ascii_lowercase%0Afrom%20functools%20import%20reduce%0Aimport%20operator%0A%0Aa,%20b,%20c,%20d,%20e,%20f,%20g,%20h,%20i,%20j,%20k,%20l,%20m,%20n,%20o,%20p,%20q,%20r,%20s,%20t,%20u,%20v,%20w,%20x,%20y,%20z%20%3D%20tuple%28%0A%20%20%20%20%28round%28abs%28random%28%29%29%20**%2010,%204%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20if%20randint%280,%201%29%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20else%20randint%2820,%2050%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20if%20randint%280,%201%29%20%25%202%20%3D%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20else%20%28'foo',%20'bar',%20'can',%20'haz',%20'bzr'%29%5Brandint%280,%204%29%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20c%20in%20ascii_lowercase%29%0A%0Al1%20%3D%20%5Ba,%20b,%20c,%20d,%20e,%20f,%20g,%20%5Bh,%20i,%20j,%20k%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20l,%20m,%20n,%20%5Bo,%20p,%20q,%20r,%20%5Bs,%20t,%20u,%20v,%20w,%20x,%20y,%20z%5D,%20a,%20b%5D,%20c,%20d,%20e%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Adef%20traverse%28lst%29%3A%0A%20%20stack%20%3D%20%5Blst%5D%0A%20%20res%20%3D%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20substack%20%3D%20stack%5B0%5D%0A%20%20subres%20%3D%20res%5B0%5D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20depth%20%3D%200%0A%0A%20%20while%20stack%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20substack%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20isinstance%28substack%5B0%5D,%20list%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20substack%20%3D%20substack%5B0%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subres.append%28%5B%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subres%20%3D%20subres%5B-1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20depth%20%2B%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20len%28substack%29%20%3E%201%20and%20not%20isinstance%28substack%5B1%5D,%20list%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subres.append%28%7B'key'%3A%20substack.pop%280%29,%20'val'%3A%20substack.pop%280%29%7D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subres.append%28substack.pop%280%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20substack%20%3D%20reduce%28operator.getitem,%20%5B0%5D%20*%20depth,%20stack%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subres%20%3D%20reduce%28operator.getitem,%20%5B-1%5D%20*%20depth,%20res%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20depth%20-%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20substack.pop%280%29%0A%0A%20%20return%20res%5B0%5D%0A%0Aprint%28l1%29%20%20%0Aprint%28traverse%28l1%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=258&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

<sub>*1. I'm not exactly sure how you're supposed to know the exact pre-names for dict keys in your output example if you're passing just lists of list to the function so I'll leave it up to you.*</sub>

Comment: With your precise function and input I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: @AT Python's default recursion limit is up to call stack of 1000. As you can clearly see [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B'foo',%20'bar',%20%5B'can',%20'haz'%5D%5D%0A%0Adef%20f%28a%29%3A%0A%20%20itr%20%3D%20iter%28a%29%0A%20%20return%20%5Bf%28x%29%20if%20isinstance%28x,%20list%29%20else%20%7B'key'%3A%20x,%20'val'%3A%20next%28itr%29%7D%20for%20x%20in%20itr%5D%0A%20%20%0Aprint%28f%28a%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=20&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)[...]

Comment: [...]call stack for this particular function and input **doesn't exceed 4** and everything works fine. I'd guess the problem lies somewhere in your current setup. Anyway, I've got a solution for you that doesn't use recursion. Check out my updated answer.